# Reference for homological cross lemma?

Tags: reference-request, homological-algebra, diagram-chasing

A colleague and I have recently found ourselves using the following result:

$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
@. @. 0 @. @. \\
@. @. @VVV @. @.\\
@. @. A @. @. \\
@. @. @VV\phi_1 V @. @. \\
0 @>>> D @>>\psi_1> B @>>\psi_2> E @>>> 0\\
@. @. @VV\phi_2 V @. @. \\
@. @. C @. @. \\
@. @. @VVV @. @. \\
@. @. 0 @. @.
\end{CD}$

If the two sequences here are exact, then $\ker(\psi_2 \circ \phi_1) \cong \ker(\phi_2\circ\psi_1)$, and similarly for cokernel.

The proof is straightforward diagram chasing, but we'd like to just cite a source for it if possible. He says he's seen a version of this referred to as the "cross lemma", but a search on this name doesn't yield much besides https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF00969298.pdf and https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82599979.pdf, both of which are working in confusingly more general contexts.

Is there a basic source on algebra where we could find this written down? Does it go by a different name?

Comment: Is it valid in abstract Abelian categories too?

Comment: @Lehs Yes, because the diagram chasing in question works in any abelian category. Alternatively, one can use the argument I give below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is a corollary of [a certain variation of] the $9$-lemma (also known as the $3\times 3$-lemma); the name "cross lemma" might not be so widely used in the literature.

You may consider the factorizations of $\psi_2\circ \phi_1$ and $\phi_2\circ\psi_1$ through their respective images, and complete the arrows $\phi_1$, $\psi_1$ to a square by taking a pullback, and $\phi_2$, $\psi_2$ by taking a pushout. Then you obtain a diagram with exact rows and columns

$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
@. 0 @. 0 @. 0 @. \\
@. @VVV @VVV @VVV @.\\
0 @>>> \bullet @>>> A @>>> \bullet @>>> 0 \\
@. @VVV @VV\phi_1 V @VVV @. \\
0 @>>> D @>>\psi_1> B @>>\psi_2> E @>>> 0\\
@. @VVV @VV\phi_2 V @VVV @. \\
0 @>>> \bullet @>>> C @>>> \bullet @>>> 0 \\
@. @VVV @VVV @VVV @. \\
@. 0 @. 0 @. 0 @.
\end{CD}$

I believe there are some modern references for this statement, but it appears precisely in this form as Proposition 16.5 of [Mitchell's "Theory of Categories"](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/mitchell.pdf) (1965).